# Django not sending rendered array to Angular

Tags: django, angular

I'm trying to build an API with Django that recieves an image, applies a filter and returns the image with the filter to the frontEnd, that it's made with Angular. But when I call the API my model does recieve the image but doesn't apply the filter and doesn't return the modified image.
And it whe using the method POST doesn't return anything, not even an error

This is my models.py:

```
def apply_filter(noisy_image, kernel):
    smoothed_image = np.zeros_like(noisy_image)
    for channel in range(noisy_image.shape[2]):
        for row in range(noisy_image.shape[0] - kernel.shape[0] + 1):
            for col in range(noisy_image.shape[1] - kernel.shape[1] + 1):
                sub_matrix = noisy_image[row:row + kernel.shape[0], col:col + kernel.shape[1], channel]
                smoothed_image[row + 1, col + 1, channel] = np.sum(sub_matrix * kernel)
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.imshow(smoothed_image.astype(np.uint8))
    ax.axis('off')
    return fig


def default_image(image_array):
    # Load image
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.imshow(image_array.astype(np.uint8))
    ax.axis('off')  # Hide axes
    return fig

def suavizado1(image_array):
    kernel_size = 12
    kernel = np.ones((kernel_size, kernel_size)) / (kernel_size ** 2)
    noise = np.random.normal(0, 10, size=image_array.shape)
    noisy_image = image_array + image_array * noise
    
    return apply_filter(noisy_image, kernel)
```

This is my views.py:

```
def processImage(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        uploaded_file = request.FILES['image']
        filter_name = request.POST.get('filter') 
        image_path = default_storage.save('uploaded_images/' + uploaded_file.name, ContentFile(uploaded_file.read()))
        print(image_path)
        #Load image
        imagen = Image.open(image_path)
        image_array = np.array(imagen)
        print(image_array)
        # aplica el filtro seleccionado
        if filter_name == 'smooth':
            output = models.suavizado1(image_array)
        elif filter_name == 'reset':
            output = models.default_image(image_array)
        else:
            # Valor predeterminado al cargar la pagina
            output = models.default_image(image_array)
        
        JsonResponse({'result': 'success'})
        buffer = io.BytesIO()
        output.savefig(buffer, format='png')
        buffer.seek(0)
        image_png = buffer.getvalue()
        buffer.close()
        graphic = base64.b64encode(image_png).decode('utf-8')

        return render(request, 'index.html', {'graphic': graphic})
```

Comment: Currently your question doesn't have anything to do with Angular. Please either remove the Angular tag, or provide code from the Angular side of your application.